# problem Addng files to document library using timer Job

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hi I Created timer job to add xml file to document library, when i run timer job first time it is missing some files to add.but when I debug the code by putting breakpoints it is adding all files to document library. When I Just run normally timer job is not adding all files to document library. when run timer job second timer it is adding all file to document library.

The problem is happening only once when I remove all files from document library and run timer job. it is adding some files only and missing some files where can I check. I am adding below code to add file to document library

```
var x = new XmlSerializer(xDoc.GetType());

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            x.Serialize(ms, xDoc);
            ms.Flush();
            string datetimeString = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.xml", DateTime.Now);
            var file = documnetlib.RootFolder.Files.AdddatetimeString, ms, true);
            SPListItem itemtoAdd = documnetlib.GetItemById(file.ListItemAllFields.ID);
            itemtoAdd["URL"] = url;
            itemtoAdd.Update();
            documnetlib.Update();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Two (or more) files can be added in one second timespan. In that case the second file will overwrite the first file because they have the same name generated by your code. That’s why when the timer job runs the second time it succeeds to add the files that have been overwritten the first time, now with different name.

When you go with debugger and breakpoints you give it more time and no duplicate names are generated for different documents.

Add a random number to the generated file names and try again.